# Why having an exponential dependence of specific heat on temperature indicate presence of energy gaps?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, superconductivity

> Key experimental contributions made the main properties of the superconductors more transparent
> before the BCS theory appeared in 1957. The observation of an exponential decay of the specific heat at
> low temperatures showed that the energy spectrum of a superconductor is gapped.

If I measure the specific heat of a substance as a function of temperature and find that low temperatures it dies exponentially can I always guess despite the material or system I have that there might a gap present in the energy spectrum or does this work only for superconductors?

Also, how does one conclude from the dependence that there must exist a gap ?

Comment: It might be worth looking at the Einstein model of a solid as a first step. There, the exponential behavior of the heat capacity at low temperatures is precisely due to the energy gap $\hbar\omega$ between the states of the oscillators making up the solid. When you move to the Debye model, there is no gap since the dispersion relation for phonons goes as $\omega=vk$, and there the heat capacity goes as $T^D$ (where $D$ is the dimension) at low temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

At $T=0$ the specific heat $C(T)$ must go to zero for any material, otherwise the entropy $S(T_a)=
{\int_0^{T_a} C(T)\,\frac{dT}{T}} $ at any temperature $T_a$ would be infinite, thus violating Nernst's postulate. For the specific case of a superconductor see [this excellent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/277054/259972).

A tell-tale sign of a superconducting transition is a positive jump $ {\Delta C\equiv C(T_c+0^-)-C(T_c+0^+)} $ in the specific heat at the critical temperature $T_c$. $C(T)$ has a jump at $T_c$ since ${C = T {dS\over dT}}$ and ${dS\over dT}$ jumps at $T_c$. Intuitively, there is a discontinuity in ${dS\over dT}$ at $T_c$, because the increase in  $S(T)$ due to the decrease in superconducting density (the density of more ordered superconducting electrons) suddenly ceases as the gap reaches zero.

See (3.56-58) in [2] or (80-84) in [3] for details.

[2] M. Tinkham Introduction to Superconductivity (2ed., MGH, 1996)

[3] Rafael M. Fernandes, Lecture Notes: [BCS theory of superconductivity](https://portal.ifi.unicamp.br/images/files/graduacao/aulas-on-line/fen-emerg/lecture_notes_BCS.pdf)